# Is there a way to query for all users and with a where clause with the new UserManager and UserStore in Asp.net MVC5?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

I was wondering if there is a way to query for all users with the new built in user methods or should I make a repository for application users?

Asp.Net MVC5 with Entity-Framework 6 and c#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you can't via the UserManager API in 1.0 RTM, this will be possible in 1.1 via UserManager.Users being an IQueryable.

You can do this via the DbContext itself if you store the DbContext/UserStore that you are using to construct the UserManager, i.e. myApplicationDbContext.Users

Comment: When approx. and will features such as adding many users to many roles, deleting users etc. be added?

Comment: Delete users is also in 1.1, which the alpha1 release should happen fairly soon.  Adding many users to many roles is probably not going to be supported with an explicit API like in old Membership.